# NTSTATUS not declared in this scope

Tags: c++

I can compile the following function on Linux under mingw64 as a Windows Executable.

```cpp
std::string get_os()
{
    std::string os;
    std::ostringstream ds;
    int ret = 0.0;
    NTSTATUS(WINAPI *RtlGetVersion)(LPOSVERSIONINFOEXW);
    OSVERSIONINFOEXW osInfo;

    *reinterpret_cast<FARPROC*>(&RtlGetVersion) = GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandleA("ntdll"), "RtlGetVersion");

    if (nullptr != RtlGetVersion)
    {
        osInfo.dwOSVersionInfoSize = sizeof osInfo;
        RtlGetVersion(&osInfo);
        ret = osInfo.dwMajorVersion;
    }

    int mw = osInfo.dwMinorVersion;
    if(ret == 5){
        switch (mw)
        {
        case 0:
            // 5.0 = Windows 2000
            os = "Windows 2000";
            break;
        case 1:
            // 5.1 = Windows XP
            os = "Windows XP";
            break;

        case 2:
            os = "Windows XP Professional";
            break;

        default:
            ds.str(""); ds.clear(); 
            ds << "Windows " << mw;
            os = ds.str();
            break;
        }
    } else if(ret == 6){
        switch (mw)
        {
        case 0:
            os = "Windows Vista";
            break;
        case 1:
            os = "Windows 7";
            break;
        case 2:
            os = "Windows 8";
            break;
        case 3:
            os = "Windows 8.1";
            break;

        default:
            ds.str(""); ds.clear(); 
            ds << "Windows " << mw;
            os = ds.str();
            break;
        }
    } else if(ret == 10){
            os = "Windows 10";
    } else {
        ds.str(""); ds.clear(); 
        ds << "Windows " << mw;
        os = ds.str();
    }
    return os;

}
```

But on Windows, I cannot compile this as I get these unknown Errors. Why?
I think I am missing some library on Windows. But all of the required stuff should be in windows.h? shouldn't it?

```
NTSTATUS(WINAPI *RtlGetVersion)(LPOSVERSIONINFOEXW);
           ^
testos.cpp:135:32: error: 'NTSTATUS' was not declared in this scope
  NTSTATUS(WINAPI *RtlGetVersion)(LPOSVERSIONINFOEXW);
                                ^
testos.cpp:135:52: error: expected primary-expression before ')' token
  NTSTATUS(WINAPI *RtlGetVersion)(LPOSVERSIONINFOEXW);
                                                    ^
testos.cpp:138:31: error: 'RtlGetVersion' was not declared in this scope
  *reinterpret_cast<FARPROC*>(&RtlGetVersion) = GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandleA("ntdll"), "RtlGetVersion");
                               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
makefile:2: recipe for target 'windows' failed
make: *** [windows] Error 1
```

Comment: The solution will be in the header files you `#included`, so please post these as well.

Comment: @Bojte These are my includes. ```#include <windows.h>
#include <wininet.h>
#include <lmcons.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <cstring>
#include <sstream>
#include <cstdio>```

Comment: Anyone? Please help I need to fix this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know this is old now but in case anyone is having the same problem.

```c
#define NTSTATUS LONG
```

Fixes the problem.